# Sync job issue, maybe network related?

Tags: sql-server, network

I have a job that syncs rows in a table between a production server and four other servers.

The problem is the job runs perfect on three servers, taking less than 2 seconds. On the fourth server, it takes over 12 seconds which causes a delay. There are no apparent indexing or statistics issues.

I talked to our systems administrator, he says the outbound packets are fine, but the problem is when the information goes back to the production server. The packet comes in 4600 bits and the network the server is using only 1600 bits and it takes time to divide the packets. He is asking if there is a way to do something in SQL Server to manage that, we told him no.

Has anyone faced this problem before? The trouble server is new and more powerful than the other three.

Comment: You need to find out if configuration is same between all servers. Also `set nocount on` in your query. Is amount of data pulled is same ? Have you considered transactional replication as alternative?

Comment: Yes it's identical data for the 4 servers

Comment: We allready using transactional replication and it won't be necessary coz we are using it for some databases